# How to call super() when referring to a member of the child class

Tags: java

I have a parent class

```
public class Parent
{
    Database m_d;
    Parent(Database d){
        m_d = d;
    }
}
```

And a child class

```
public class Child extends Parent implements java.lang.AutoCloseable
{
    ChildDatabase m_d
    Child()
    {
        // Error on the next statement:
        // "Cannot reference m_database before supertype constructor
        // has been called"
        super(m_d = CreateDatabase());
    }
}
```

Note that `ChildDatabase` implements `java.lang.AutoCloseable` which is a reason why I need to keep a `ChildDatabase` reference in the `Child` class. Note that `ChildDatabase` extends `Database`.

The problem is that `super(m_d = CreateDatabase());` is not valid since you can't refer to child class members in the call to `super`.

Is there a syntax I'm missing which would allow me to do this? An alternative would be to implement a `getDatabase()` method in `Parent`, and cast that result to a `ChildDatabase` to store as `m_d;`, but that seems a smell to me.

Note that `CreateDatabase` can be `static`.

Comment: Can you make `CreateDatabase` static in your situation?

Comment: You don't need a ChildDatabase as it'll already be reference by m_d of the parent

Comment: @Ferrybig: Yes I can.

Comment: @azro: But that one will have the base type, and that's not auto-closable.

Comment: would be nice to see a [mcve]

Comment: A question, but ChildDatabase extends Database ?

Comment: @aurox: Yes it does. Apologies that I missed that. I've added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
public abstract class Parent<DB extends Database>
{
    DB m_d;

    Parent()
    {
        m_d = getDatabase();
    }

    abstract DB getDatabase();
}
```

and

```
public class Child extends Parent<ChildDatabase> implements java.lang.AutoCloseable
{

    Child()
    {
        // do something with this.m_d here
    }

    @Override
    ChildDatabase getDatabase()
    {
        return createChildDatabase();
    }
}
```

Then you can even use AutoCloseable features directly on this.m_d (like try...with etc).

Comment: That's wonderful. In the end getDatabase() didn't need to be abstract, and I could make it `protected`, and there was no need for the shadowing in the child class. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

By introducing a getter of the object in the parent class you could write it :

```
public class Child extends Parent implements java.lang.AutoCloseable
{
    ChildDatabase m_d;
    Child()
    {
        // Error on the next statement:
        // "Cannot reference m_database before supertype constructor
        // has been called"
        super(CreateDatabase());
        this.m_d = (ChildDatabase)getMd();
    }
}
```

But the downcast is undesirable, it may fail at runtime and it looks a hack.
If the subclass needs to refer to the field as a `ChildDataBase`, it should be explicit in the constructor itself such as :

```
ChildDatabase m_d;
Child(ChildDatabase childDb)
{
    super(childDb);
    m_d = childDb;
}
```

In a general way dependencies should be explicit if not an implementation detail since It favors the testability and the switch to other implementations.

Note that I don't like either a lot this solution.
This still duplicates the field in the hierarchy.
The problem here is that you want to value the same object with for the parent constructor and the child constructor a distinct declared type.
You should not. It is error prone for people reading your code.
Using a generic class is probably better and would allow subclasses to specify the subclass for Database fields.
It will still require to provide the getter in the parent class.

```
public class Parent<T ? extends DataBase>
{
    private T m_d;
    Parent(T d){
        m_d = d;
    }
    public T getMd(){
      return m_d;
    }
}
```

With hidden dependency :

```
public class Child extends Parent<ChildDataBase> implements AutoCloseable
{
  Child(){
    super(CreateDatabase());      
  }
  void foo(){
     ChildDataBase md = getMd(); // return the generic type
  }
}
```

With exposed dependency :

```
public class Child extends Parent<ChildDataBase> implements AutoCloseable
{
  Child(ChildDataBase md){
    super(md);      
  }
  void foo(){
     ChildDataBase md = getMd(); // return the generic type
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is simply **not feasible**.

Following the [Java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), no class field member can be initialized before the call to `super` (constructor) has been done.

As you are implementing a specific behavior within your `Child` class, a workaround, may be to omit the local `m_d` field passing the desired `Database` instance reference over a factory mixed with a generic formal type for the sub-type `Database`.

Here down the `Parent` class type:

```java
public class Parent<D extends Database> {
    D m_d;

    Parent(D m_d) {
        m_d = m_d;
    }

    protected D getDatabase() {
        return this.m_d;
    }
}
```

And the `Child` would be as follows:

```java
public class Child extends Parent<ChildDatabase> {

    private Child(ChildDatabase m_d) {
        super(m_d);
    }

    private static ChildDatabase createDatabase() {
        return null;
    }

    public static class ChildFactory {

        public static Child createChild() {
            return new Child(createDatabase());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to have the field `m_d` in both `Parent` and `Child`? Isn't it sufficient to have it only in `Parent`? And simply have `super(createDatabase());` in `Child`'s constructor like in below code:

```
public class Parent
{
  Database m_d;

  Parent(Database d)
  {
    m_d = d;
  }
}

class Child extends Parent implements java.lang.AutoCloseable
{
  Child()
  {
    super(createDatabase());
  }

  private static ChildDatabase createDatabase()
  {
    return new ChildDatabase();
  }

  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception
  {
  }
}

class Database
{
}

class ChildDatabase extends Database implements java.lang.AutoCloseable
{
  @Override
  public void close() throws Exception
  {
  }
}
```